# Connecting to named server from a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am trying to access a named postgres server from inside a docker container. I can access the server via it's IP address, but not its name. I've tried `--net=host` and `-p ServerName:5432:5432` options on the `docker run` command.

I will demonstrate the issue:

```sh
# on the host
$ ping ServerName
# This works
$ ping 10.1.1.25
# Works

# Then enter container with:
$ winpty docker exec -it containerName bash
$ ping 10.1.1.25
# Works
$ ping ServerName
# Does NOT work
```

I would guess that I need to give docker some kind of mapping from the hosts knowlegde of the network to the container. I presume that would be through the network functionality, but I can't find any instructions that I understand.

And before anyone suggests it, the postgres instance cannot be moved, including being moved into a docker container of it's own.

Output of `docker ps` is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
15c7903f7ccd        imageName           "tail -f /dev/null"      47 minutes ago      Up 47 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8888/tcp   containerName
```

Comment: please show the output of `docker ps`. the whole idea is to get docker container name

Comment: if we have a container name then we can exec inside the docker container. once we are inside docker container we can ping postgress server

Comment: named server? what do you mean by this, name of the postgress server? I think i know if you want to communicate between docker containers in docker env then need to use container name instead of localhost!

Comment: I do not want to communicate between containers. The postgres instance is NOT in a container (otherwise I believe a bridge network would be a very quick and easy fix).

Comment: So the Postgres is at your local machine(let's say windows machine) and you are trying to access postgress from inside docker container. is it ?

Comment: In simple words, you want to access a `DNS` from inside the docker container! Am i right /

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/dns-resolution-not-working-in-containers/36246/2 I think this will be useful for you, please have a look.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/868403

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I needed to use the `--dns` option in `docker run` command. Then, inside the container, I needed to use the fully qualified name i.e. `serverName.companyName.com` instead of just `serverName`.

Thanks to @Dupinder Singh for pointing me to some useful DNS articles (see comments on the question).